# Entry point and main method in PE executable Windows

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering, executable, entry-point

How can I find the main method in the PE executable file, should I find the entry point address and start from that point or find three pushes of the stack in case the PE is written in C?

Answer (score 2):

There are not going to be 3 pushes because `main` is not the real entry point on Windows. The compiler will insert extra code that initializes things and then calls `main`/`WinMain`. There is probably too much code between the real start and `main` to automate finding `main`. You would have to consider multiple versions of Visual Studio and MinGW. And some exe files do not use the C run-time at all and execute directly from the real entrypoint.

The entry point is a function that takes zero arguments. Its address is the load address of the .exe (Starting with MZ) + [`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.AddressOfEntryPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_optional_header32).

Comment: compiler of course not insert any extra code. simply usual well known `main\WinMain` not set as entry point (instead `[w]mainCRTStartup\[w]WinMainCRTStartup`) but what we direct set as entry - exactly this and will be. aslo formal entry point take 1 agrument (begin from vista) - address of PEB. but almost always it ignored.

Comment: @RbMm In 99% of cases you will be looking at an .exe where the compiler has inserted code between `mainCRTStartup` and `main`. I even addressed this in my answer. Also, I'm unaware of any documentation that says the PEP is a supported parameter...

Comment: i simply mean that not compiler insert. but linker, because we reference (usually implicit) this code. of course if not do different between compiler and linker. also this insert only when we really refer to crt entry point. about adress of PEB, of course this is undocumented and not useful , but formal windows pass this parameter to exe entry point